# Azure Recovery Services Vault is not refreshing backup information

Tags: azure, backup

We are evaluating Azure ASR for cloud Backup and Site Recovery. 
Started a month ago with Backup services to backup files, folders and SQL servers and everything worked fine, MABS is installed in server A.

We have also added a physical server to Site recovery, installing the Azure site recovery on the same server A. Since then, every dashboard referring to Backup information has not been updated though its clear that GRS Storage is used for backups.

Tried to uninstall/re-install MABS without any success, any ideas? there are no errors in the MABS MMC console.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to install backup (MABS) and site recovery on the same machine since both Services are using similar tasks there will be lot of conflicts.

Comment: I got a different response from MS Pre-sales stating that this config is valid. 
Of course, i wouldn't be surprised if some services overlap causing the problem. Is there a reference article or KB where you got this info Vikranth?